# ClickOnce launcher doesn't pick up the latest version at application startup

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

At our company we use clickonce deployment for the client part of our client/server application. Clickonce package is deployed to an IIS server with FrontPage extensions installed. We do  our compiling, signing and publishing to IIS directly from Visual Studio 2010. Our clickonce package is set up so that it check for newer version *at each application startup*.

The application has ~100 users@remote machines. Lately, when we publish the latest release some of the clients (about 10-15%) end up still using the old release. When we connect remotely to one of the clients and start the application we see that the clickonce launcher checks for a newer version and then starts the application without updating. We then have to uninstall the application and install it again via the clickonce-generated webpage in order to get the latest version.

Any ideas why this is happening and how can we prevent it? Is there any way to enable logging, to see why the launcher isn't picking up a newer version even though it checks for it at application startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and launch the app on one of the machines that isn't working. Verify it's checking for updates at the correct location and the update call is succeeding.

Comment: Will try that if possible, the problem is that it's too intrusive for the client (even remote connecting is a huge pain because of the client's security policies). Strangely all of our in-house test clients work ok. Although this gave me an idea, I may have more luck looking at our IIS logs when once we establish the client's IP at the time of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options you may want to try that my team uses on some of our deployments depending on the need.  These may not suit your need exactly as they each have caveats, but should solve your problem.

1. Set "The applications is available online only" in the Publish settings.  (Default is offline mode which installs to windows like a normal program)  This mode re-downloads the application at each launch from the publish.html, and does not install it in windows.  You have to launch the html or setup.exe each time.  We get around the annoyance of this by making "menu" applications that just have a bunch of buttons/links that point to the applications we have out there in online modes so the users can find them.
2. If you still want to stick with offline mode like normal try setting the minimum required version = the current version.  This should force ClickOnce to get that latest version each time, this seems to work for me, but I have not thoroughly tested this.

Comment: "This mode re-downloads the application at each launch". This is wrong. Offline and Online are virtually identical. There are only 3 differences. 1. Offline adds a Add/Remove entry  2. Offline adds a start menu shortcut.  3. Online apps have a 250 MB cache; the only time they will be re-downloaded is if the cache goes over 250 MB and the apps are scavenged.

Comment: Thank you Brett, I've already considered that scenario, but the problem is that our client application enables data-entry in offline mode, with the offline data being posted to the server when the user connects back to the internet. This effectively prevents me from using either of the proposed solutions, because in the 1st case application wouldn't be available at all when offline, and in the 2nd the user could not post offline data to the server because after update it couldn't deserialize offline data written with older schema (almost every update so far changed the data-model).

Comment: Besides, if detection of a newer version is already not working then I'm almost 100% sure that the solution #2 wouldn't work for my problem.